Require a-z or 0-9 after using character - regex
For my regex I am looking for a solution to require a character a-z or number 0-9 after a minus character.
For example
test- (return false)
test-one or test-2 (return true)

test-one- (return false)
test-one-2 (return true)

I think it's like a if statement but how can I translate this to an expression?

Does - have to be in the expression at all?

What type of regex implementation do you use?

Does - have to be in the expression at all? No it is not required but if the - is used require a character a-z or 0-9 I need it in JavaScript

-[a-z0-9] will match - followed by a letter or number.

@Barmar does return false (test-one-2)

This would be old-school: ^([ a-z0-9]*-[a-z0-9]+)*$ https://regex101.com/r/lGfdZt/1

If you want to find dashes that are not followed by a word character: -\B (probably not what you're after but worth to mention if so).

Use a negative lookahead at the beginning of the regular expression, to prohibit - followed by something other than [a-z0-9]:
^(?!.*-(?:$|[^a-z0-9])).

DEMO

What's the problem? There's a - after the first -, which isn't allowed.

Thanks. I didn't realize you were showing a different regexp, I thought you just added another test case to mine.

One could use a double-negative by matching
^(?!.*-(?![a-z\d]))

If the string is valid the regex will match a zero-length string at the begining of the string. Alternatively, append .* to the regex for it to match the entire string if it is valid.
Demo
The regular expression reads, "beginning at the start of the string, one cannot match, following zero or more characters, a hyphen that is not followed by a lowercase letter or digit".
The expression can be written in extended (a.k.a. free-spacing) mode to make it self-documenting.
^            # match the beginning of the string
(?!          # begin a positive lookahead
  .*-        # match >= 0 characters followed by a hyphen
  (?!        # begin an inner negative lookahead  
    [a-z\d]  # match a lowercase letter or digit
  )          # end the (inner) negative lookahead
)            # end the (outer) negative lookahead


I added the . at the end in my demo so that you can actually see that it's matching something, rather than returning zero-length matches.
